# Why does the adjoint representation appear in the definition of a connection 1-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

When defining the a connection 1-form $A$ on a principal $G$-bundle we require that
$$r^*_gA = Ad_{g^{-1}} \circ A, \quad \forall g \in G.$$
Here $r_g^*$ is the pullback of right multiplication by $g$, denoted $r_g$.

I am having some trouble understanding where this condition comes form or why it is important. Why is the adjoint representation appearing here?

Comment: Compute concretely for the case of the matrix of connection forms for the (orthonormal) frame bundle of a Riemannian manifold of dimension $\ge 3$.

Comment: @TedShifrin The textbook I am using does not/has not yet introduced a matrix of connection forms. So far all I know is what an Ehresmann connection is (a distribution of horizontal tangent spaces that is right-invariant). Is it possible to build an intuition off this alone? I assume connections are defined more generally than Ehresmann connections?

Comment: I strongly suggest you look at some concrete treatments of connections with moving frames before jumping into the deep end of the pool. You are asking for motivation/understanding. That’s how to achieve that.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am following Hamilton's *Mathematical Gauge Theory*, I'm guessing he skipped some of that material to get to gauge theories as fast as possible. I would like to learn more about the treatment you suggested as I'm having trouble developing an intuition with this fast paced approach. Is there any textbook you can recommend to supplement Hamilton's book?

Comment: Look at Spivak, volume 2. It’s a bit wordy, but he interweaves/connects all the approaches to connections. Pick and choose appropriately. Chern/Chen/Lam is a treatment by a master of the subject.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: I think it is more intuitive to think about the horizontal distribution $\mathcal{H}$ which is determined by the connection. In this case, the condition becomes $\mathcal{H}_{pg}=(dr_g)_p\mathcal{H}_p$, which is a very reasonable invariance condition to impose, given that a principal bundle should be encoding symmetries. Then you ask: what does this mean for the $1$-form $A$? And the answer is $\text{Ad}$-equivariance.

Comment: @QuaereVerum, I agree that the invariance condition is reasonable, but if you look at the frame bundle associated with a vector bundle and a connection on the vector bundle (whose definition is quite natural and obvious), then the invariance property of the induced connection on the frame bundle is forced on you.

Comment: @QuaereVerum Thank you for your comment. Could you elaborate on the last part of your comment where you mention Ad-equivariance being the right answer to how symmetries are encoded in the 1-form $A$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, I think the natural starting point is that of a horizontal distribution on $\pi:P\to M$, i.e. $TP=\ker d\pi\oplus\mathcal{H}$. The notion of a principal $G$-bundle $P$ is meant to encode "internal symmetries" (at least, when viewed from the perspective of the standard model for instance), encoded by the group action $r_g:P\to P$. So the natural condition to impose on $\mathcal{H}$ in the presence of such a symmetry, is that $(dr_g)_p\mathcal{H}_p=\mathcal{H}_{r_g(p)}$.

Denote the projection $TP\to\ker\pi$ by $\nu$, and denote by $j_p:G\to P$ the map $g\mapsto r_g(p)$. Then $(dj_p)_e:T_eG=\mathfrak{g}\to (\ker\pi)_p$ is an isomorphism. Given a horizontal distribution, we define a $1$-form $A$ by $A_p=(dj_p)^{-1}\circ\nu:T_pP\to\mathfrak{g}$. Given a $1$-form $A$, we can also define a distribution $\ker A\subset TP$. They are just two ways to represent the same idea.

**Theorem:** The $1$-form $A$ is $\text{Ad}$-equivariant if and only if the horizontal distribution $\mathcal{H}$ is $r_g$-invariant.

*Proof.* Suppose the distribution is right-invariant. Suppose $X\in T_pP$. Then $X=X_v+X_h\in \ker d\pi\oplus\mathcal{H}$. We can write $X_v=\eta^\sharp_p$, where $\eta\in\mathfrak{g}$ and $\eta^\sharp$ denotes the associated fundamental vector field on $P$. Then one finds (check the details in the last equality)
$$A_p(\eta^\sharp_p)=(dj_p)^{-1}(\nu(\eta^\sharp_p))=(dj_p)^{-1}(\eta^\sharp_p)=\eta$$
Using $dr_g\eta^\sharp=(\text{Ad}_{g^{-1}}\eta)^\sharp$, we get
$$A_{pg}((dr_g)_p\eta^\sharp_p)=A_{pg}((\text{Ad}_{g^{-1}}\eta)^\sharp_{pg})=\text{Ad}_{g^{-1}}\eta=\text{Ad}_{g^{-1}}A_p(\eta^\sharp_p)$$
This takes care of the vertical component of $X$. For the horizontal component, one has $A_{pg}((dr_g)_p X_h)=0=\text{Ad}_{g^{-1}}A_p(X_h)$ of course.

That proves one direction. I won't go through the proof of the converse, as you can find it in many texts. The one I used when studying this is called "Differential Geometry: Connections, Curvature and Characteristic Classes" by Loring Tu, and it is an extremely well-written book that I would recommend to anyone trying to learn gauge theory. For a full answer to your question, I refer to proposition 27.13, theorem 28.1 and theorem 28.5 in said book.

As you can see though, the crux of the story is that the fundamental vector field transforms in a way that involves the adjoint representation, i.e. the equality $dr_g\eta^\sharp=(\text{Ad}_{g^{-1}}\eta)^\sharp$. And this is what leads to the $\text{Ad}$-equivariance of the connection $1$-form being equivalent to the invariance of the horizontal distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I think this is true because a connection $A$ on a principal $G$-bundle is modeled on the Maurer-Cartan form on $G$, which is a $\mathfrak g$-valued 1-form $\omega$ defined at $g\in G$ as $\omega_g := (L_{g^{-1}})_*:T_gG\to \mathfrak g$. (Here we identify $\mathfrak g$ with $T_1G$.)

This form is left-invariant - indeed it is the left invariant extension of the identity map/identification $T_1G\to \mathfrak g$ to the rest of $TG$.
(Note this means that, at $1\in G$, $\omega(X) = X$ for every $X\in T_1G = \mathfrak g$ which is the other property of connections.)

Then we have
$$R_{g^{-1}}^*\omega = R_{g^{-1}}^*L_g^*\omega = \text{Ad}_g \omega.$$

If you identify one fiber of a principal bundle with $G$, and restrict your connection $A$ to this (vertical) fiber, I believe you should get that $A$ is the Maurer-Cartan form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.